# What problems will "microsoft office diagnostic" detect

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I am running Outlook 2007.

Inside the "Help" menu, I decided to see what it would do.

It does not appear to have found any problems, and it also does not seem to tell me when I should run it.

Anyone have any real-world experiences?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this tool if your having different issues with this product.

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/results-of-microsoft-office-diagnostics-HA001186343.aspx) you'll find possible common problems that can show up in the results (after the tool done with the scan)